# Postgresql Update Table row values by Grouped Column

Tags: postgresql, update, group-by, postgresql-9.5

First of all a little bit of background:

I currently have a table which contains call data both inbound and outbound from my business, up until recently there was no **api_id** data available, however this has come in with the last update to my suppliers API, as such i have some historical call data that can be grouped by **call_id**.

What i am looking to do is update the existing rows in the database that do not have an api_id with a random string of characters grouping them by their call_id.

```
| ... | call_id | api_id |
|------------------------|
| ... | 123     | AAA    |
| ... | 456     |        |
| ... | 456     |        |
| ... | 788     |        |
| ... | 789     |        |
| ... | 789     |        |
```

Would then become:

```
| ... | call_id | api_id |
|------------------------|
| ... | 123     | AAA    |
| ... | 456     | GHA    |
| ... | 456     | GHA    |
| ... | 788     | ZPM    |
| ... | 789     | LFF    |
| ... | 789     | LFF    |
```

Effectively an update by grouped query, which i have done a search for but was unable to find anything.

If anyone here could help or point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Database Technology: **Postgresql 9.5.4**

Comment: if that can really be a random string (i.e. the contents doesn't matter), then why not just use the `call_id`? `update the_table set api_id = call_id::text where api_id is null`?

Comment: ..... Wow, i was so tied up in grouping on the update i didnt even think about that, just for future reference, is it possible to do what the question is asking however?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer - as the dummy value in `api_id` doesn't matter: use the `call_id`:

```
update the_table 
    set api_id = call_id::text 
where api_id is null;
```

---

Complicated answer:

Assuming you have some way of generating a random string, you could do something like this (untested):

```
update the_table
   set api_id = t.random_string
from (
  select distinct on (call_id) call_id, random_string() as random_string
  from the_table
  where api_id is null
  order by call_id
) t 
where t.call_id = the_table.call_id
 and the_table.api_id is null;
```

This generates one row with per call_id in the inner query and generates a random value for each of that. This result is then used to update the target table.

The above assumes that *if* there is already value for a specific `call_id` there is one for **all** rows. It won't "fill" in missing api_id for other rows (e.g. if there was a row with `call_id = 123` but no `api_id`)

Comment: Why `distinct on (call_id)` and not the simple `group by call_id`?

Comment: not sure what you mean. `select a, random() from t group by a;` works fine in my machine.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: hmm, you are right. But I don't think it would make a performance difference